# GIT Auto-Fetch Not Updating Org

Tags: git

I am finally making the transition from Eclipse-->SVN to Visual Studio Code-->GIT for SFDC development.

One major issue:  When you refreshed from your SVN repo into Eclipse the code was not only updated in your project, but it auto-pushed to your org, so you could see if there were any issues with checked in code from other people.

To my horror I have noticed that when code changes are auto-fetched from GIT they are silently applied to my local project but NOT pushed to the connected org.  So the org is in an unknown state versus your project.

Is there a workaround for this??

Thanks.

Comment: `sfdx force:source:push`?

Comment: Sounds like you're looking for functionality that is built into the [Deploy on Save](https://salesforcedx-vscode.netlify.app/tools/vscode/en/user-guide/deploy-on-save/) VS Code extension.

Comment: Is it?  I already have that enabled.  When I save, it saves to the org also.  I am talking about periodic auto-updates from the remote git repo.  Those do not deploy on "save" unfortunately.   And sfdx force:source:push works fine but not automatically.....